# Error: Creating default object from empty value (laravel)

Tags: laravel

so I just want to simply update in crud with Laravel.

This is the error:

[image]

This is **My Controller**:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     $request->validate([
        'category_fam'=>'required',
        'student_name'=>'required',
        'parent_name'=>'required',
        'grade'=>'required',
        'phone'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required',
    ]);
    $contact                = contact::find($id);
    $contact->category_fam  = $request->get('category_fam');
    $contact->student_name  = $request->get('student_name');
    $contact->parent_name   = $request->get('parent_name');
    $contact->grade         = $request->get('grade');
    $contact->phone         = $request->get('phone');
    $contact->email         = $request->get('email');
    $contact->save();

    return redirect()->route('contact')->with('success','Contact updated successfully');
}
```

this is my view, that the error above point to:

```
<form action="{{ route('contact.edit.update',$contact->id) }}" method="POST">
@csrf
@method('PATCH')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group form-box">
            <label for="category_fam">Category Family</label>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="category_fam" id="category_fam" value="Student" checked> Student</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="category_fam" id="category_fam" value="Parent"> Parent</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="category_fam" id="category_fam" value="Other"> Other</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my route:

```
Route::post('/contact/edit', 'WC\ContactController@update')->name('contact.edit.update');
```

so how to resolve this? other Controller works fine and I follow the pattern for updating.

Comment: Could we see your routes  especially this route :: contact.edit.update ?

Comment: you have no data with that id

Comment: i've post my route

Comment: Can you update your routes and model to this question?

Comment: use your browser to check if the option tag is really getting the value, by inspecting the element. you can also try to make the field category_fam in your database nullable

Answer (score 0):

As I can tell, you're not getting any data from your request. Did you try to `dd()` your request before you update it? Also, in your form, I noticed that in your opening you use "POST" method, but below you define "PATCH" method. One more thing, do you input any data in your form before you try to save it?

Comment: The `POST` and `PATCH` methods are correct. It's how Laravel deals with `update`.

Comment: so when i try to dd() or print_r() it gives "to few arguments to function"

Comment: Did you use it like this: dd($contact)

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei never saw it used like that. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: yup, i use it like that dd($contact)

Answer (score 0):

Your route is not correct based on your form. In the form you have `PATCH` method so the route must be `patch`. And most important this is that you must put variable in the route definition:

```
Route::patch('/contact/edit/{id}', 'WC\ContactController@update')->name('contact.edit.update');
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can do is first you can update your route to this:

**From Post**

```
Route::post('/contact/edit', 'WC\ContactController@update')->name('contact.edit.update');
```

**To Patch**

```
Route::patch('/contact/edit', 'WC\ContactController@update')->name('contact.edit.update');
```

Alternatively you can just remove this `@method('PATCH')` in your form and it should still work with post in the route ..

After all this check if you are getting the data in your controller:

```
dd($id) and also dd(contact::find($id));
```

Good Luck ..

Comment: what method should i use in the form action?

Comment: but i got this error " The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE."

Comment: its up there, below my view

Answer (score -1):

after i change from

```
$contact = contact::find($id);
to 
$contact = contact::find(1);
```

it works well

thanks everyone